# Can I create an *un*named scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope, anonymous-scope

I know you can create named scopes in Rails, which allow you to specify conditions which can then be built on later:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:active => true}

...

MyModel.active.find(...)
```

This works by creating a proxy object which isn't evaluated until later on. What I want to know is if it's possible to create a dynamic *un*named scope?

By which I mean, is there a method 'foo' with which I can go

```
scope = MyModel.foo(:conditions => {:target_id => 4})
```

and then pass `scope` around as a proxy object that I can do more `.find`s or other scoped calls on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, check [Anonymous Scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes):

```
def find_products
  scope = Product.scoped({})
  scope = scope.conditions "products.name LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%" unless keywords.blank?
  scope = scope.conditions "products.price >= ?", minimum_price unless minimum_price.blank?
  scope = scope.conditions "products.price <= ?", maximum_price unless maximum_price.blank?
  scope = scope.conditions "products.category_id = ?", category_id unless category_id.blank?
  scope
end
```

Comment: That's perfect, and it's only documented in one file [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope.html] which I can't imagine I'd ever look at otherwise